# How can I log into or out of a Lubuntu guest account?

Tags: lubuntu, users, password-recovery

I discovered I had a guest user account logged in when I tried to shut down and Lubuntu told me I couldn't.  When I try to switch users from my administrator account to the guest account I am asked for a password.  My friend, who had logged in as a guest, claims he did not create a password.

Ideally I'd like someone will tell me how to get into this guest account, but I will be satisfied if all I get is advice on the best way to shutdown and eliminate the guest account.  Thanks!

Comment: Note, I did try clicking through but it won't accept a blank password.  Nor were our guesses successful.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo shutdown now` ?